# Passing a list of rows from another table in a model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a `Products` table and a `ProductVM` view model, and in `ProductVM` I want need to have a list of rows from another table (`Categories`), so I can display that in a dropdown list when adding a new product.

I have not been able to that so I've used `ViewBag` to pass to the view and make a dropdown list, but I know I should do it via the model but don't know how.

ProductVM

```
public class ProductVM
    {

        public ProductVM()
        {
        }

        public ProductVM(ProductDTO productDTO)
        {
            Id = productDTO.Id;
            Name = productDTO.Name;
            Description = productDTO.Description;
            CategoryId = productDTO.Id;
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
    }
```

ActionMethod:

```
public ActionResult AddProduct()
        {
            Db db = new Db();

            var result = from r in db.Categories
                         select new { r.Name, r.Id };

            ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "Name");

            return View();
        }
```

The `Categories` table just has 2 columns, `Id` and `Name`.

And to be clear, what I have now works, I just wanna do it via the model completely and not use `ViewBag`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a property to your view model

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
```

and in the controller use

```
var model = new ProductVM()
{
    Categories = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "Name"
}; 
return View(model);
```

Note you can also use

```
Categories = db.Categories.Select(x => new SelectListItem()
{
    Value = x.Id.ToString(), // assumes Id is not typeof string
    Text = x.Name
})
```